# Vine identification

Tags: identification, vines

This germinated out of nowhere. Is this a squash or pumpkin plant?

[image]

"access_token must be set" when trying to upload photo?

Comment: My first guess would be watermelon.

Comment: OH, we did have kids spitting watermelon seeds all over the place over the summer!  Nice call.  Make it an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like watermelon vine. Wait and see what grows on it. Some of the big ones take months to develop so chances are you will not have time for fruit.

Comment: Over the summer, our kids were spitting watermelon seeds all over the patio. I would say this is 99% certainty.